# I can't run/open viber

Tags: command-line, viber

I'm new user of Linux instead of Windows. I'm using Xubuntu 16.04, I installed the viber on my computer, but it does not work. I download file viber.deb from http://viber.com, and install it at the command : `sudo dpkg-i viber.deb`
When I run the application

```
/opt/viber/Viber
```

This is the error message:

```
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb".
Available platform plugins are: eglfs, minimalegl, minimal, linuxfb, offscreen, wayland-egl, wayland, xcb.
Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Have you installed something Qt related? How do you installed Viber?

Comment: I download file viber.deb from http://www.viber.com/, and install it at the command : sudo dpkg-i viber.deb

Comment: So, 1. should we assume you *didn't* install anything Qt related prior to installing Viber? And 2. Is your system fully updated? *sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade*

Comment: OK, I'm running the update command. I will check back later when completed.

Comment: update has finished. And the problem is still not solved. :D

Comment: We still don't have a clear "yes" or "no"re: Qt. Anyway, something to try before reinstalling is to delete the Viber profile (look for a hidden folder .Viber).

Comment: Does running `sudo apt-get install xcb` solve it?

Comment: @terdon I just tested in 16.04, installed and run fine. No *xcb* installed before and after so it seems *xcb* isn't required? What bugs me is this being a Qt related error.

Comment: @CelticWarrior yeah, that was just the first hit for `xcb`. Actually, [these](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=xcb&mode=filename&suite=xenial&arch=amd64) seem like far better candidates. If you've managed to install, could you check the output of `dpkg -l | grep '^ii.*libxcb'` and report which one(s) you have installed?

Comment: @terdon  http://pastebin.com/tjDY31aa

Comment: I found out how to fix this problem. Had to install libqt5gui5: `sudo apt-get install libqt5gui5` and then re-install Viber. Thank you very much everyone.

Comment: @NguyenAnh could you please post that as an answer and [accept it](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) so the question can be marked as answered?

Answer (score 5):

I found out how to fix this problem.
Had to install libqt5gui5:
`sudo apt-get install libqt5gui5`
and then re-install Viber.

Comment: This has solved my problem with vorta backup on xubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 5):

Try to run it with option `%u` like

```
/opt/viber/Viber %u
```